# External editor in Libre-Office

Tags: libreoffice

In Libre-Office, is it possible to edit a selection with an external editor, such as Vim or Emacs?

To write this, I call Vim from Qutebrowser, i.e. mark the window and press ctrl+e.  That opens an instance of Vim with whatever was in the window.  When I close the buffer, its new contents are put into the window in Qutebrowser.  Something similar in Libre-Office would help.

I ask, not because I want to use Libre-Office, but because I have to collaborate with someone who uses Word.

PS.  Ideally, italics should be converted to something that can be edited in plain text, such as \it{this}.

Comment: Copy and paste?

Comment: @Scott, yes, but that's not ideal.

Comment: @fixer1234, is it the what or the why that is unclear to you?  have you tried vim?

Comment: As someone who uses both Vim and LO every day, it sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: @fixer1234: Toothrot edited the question minutes after responding to my comment.   ISTM that revision explains what the OP wants.   By comparison, copy and paste would be cumbersome and error-prone.

Comment: @fixer1234, well a word processor contains an editor; my problem is that it is invariably a very poor editor.

Comment: Click!  Sorry, I just wasn't making the mental connection because I would never envision a scenario where it would be easier to edit a word processing document by opening it in office software and editing it a chunk at a time in a text editor.  Guess that's why there's vanilla and chocolate ice cream.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following [Python macro](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language).  Go to *Tools -> Customize* to run it at the press of a keystroke.

```
import os
import tempfile
import uno

def edit_with_vim():
    doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oVC = doc.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
    data = oVC.getString()
    encoded_data = data.encode("utf8")
    fileTemp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete = False)
    fileTemp.write(encoded_data)
    fileTemp.close()
    os.system('gvim -c "set encoding=utf8" %s' % (fileTemp.name))

g_exportedScripts = edit_with_vim,
```

**EDIT**:

After browsing the link above, see https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=12882 for a tutorial on customizing a key command to run the macro.

**EDIT 2**:

This code sends changes back to Writer.

```
import io
import os
from subprocess import call
import sys
import tempfile
import uno

def edit_with_vim():
    doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oVC = doc.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
    textstring = oVC.getString()
    text_bytes = textstring.encode("utf8")
    tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete = False)
    tempfilename = tf.name
    tf.write(text_bytes)
    tf.close()
    if os.name == 'nt':
        GVIM = "C:/Windows/gvim.bat"
    else:
        GVIM = "/usr/bin/gvim"
    call([
        GVIM, "-f",
        "-c", '"set encoding=utf8"',
        tempfilename])
    with io.open(tempfilename, 'r+b') as fh:
        fh.seek(0)
        edited_bytes = fh.read()
    os.unlink(tempfilename)
    edited_string = edited_bytes.decode("utf8")
    edited_string = edited_string.strip()
    oVC.setString(edited_string)

g_exportedScripts = edit_with_vim,
```

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't obvious to me how to proceed after clicking /customize/.

Comment: @Toothrot: See edited answer.

Comment: I don't have anything in macros/user/standard but module1, so the instruction for binding a key doesn't work.

Comment: Did you see the link that says "Python macro" above?  It does work, but you must follow the instructions.  If you have already put the .py file in the correct location but it does not appear under "My Macros", then be sure that python-uno is installed.  See http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html for a tutorial.

Comment: Trying to, but so far I can't find the directories.  I have no directory in ~ that's called .openoffice something or .libreoffice something.

Comment: Created a chat room at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/69284/external-editor-in-libre-office?tab=general.  I tried to give you permission - let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: result of chat: this works only one way.  it would be excellent if Jim, or anyone, would improve the code to take the buffer altered in vim back to LO.   also, the location of scripts in Linux is `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python`.  the last two dirs must be created manually.

Comment: Done; see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks!  There is a comma missing at the end, but impossible to edit less than 6 chars.

Comment: Okay, fixed it.